# Simple Models in Epistemic Logic

Tags: logic

I'm working through the book 'Epistemic Logic for AI and Computer Science' by Meyer and van der Hoek and got stuck in a proof on the class of $S5$ models for single agents, the class of $S5_1$-models for short.

To fix some terminology: Let a *Kripke-model* for $S5_1$ be a structure $M=(S, R, \pi)$, where $S \not = \emptyset, R \subseteq S \times S$ is an equivalence relation and $\pi:S \rightarrow 2^\Phi$, for a set of atoms $\Phi$. Let a *reduced* $S5_1$-model be a Kripke-model for $S5_1$, where $R = S \times S$ and let a *simple* model for $S5_1$ be a Kripke-model for $S5_1$, where $\pi$ is injective. So in simple models states $s, s' \in S$ are identified iff $\pi(s) = \pi(s')$.

Now Meyer and van der Hoek prove the following proposition (proposition 1.7.4.4 according to their own numbering).

> Every reduced $S5_1$-model $M$ is bisimilar to a simple $S5_1$-model $M'$.The bisimulation $\rho$ can be chosen in such a way that $dom(\rho) = S, ran(\rho) = S'$.

The proof they give is mostly straightforward: Let $[s]_\pi = \{s' \in S: \pi(s) = \pi(s') \}$, for any $s \in S$. Then $S= \bigcup_{s' \in S'}[s']_\pi$, for some $S'\subseteq S$ with $\pi(s_1) \not = \pi(s_2)$, for all $s_1, s_2 \in S'$. Let $M' = (S', R', \pi')$ with  $S'$ as above, $R' = S' \times S'$ and $\pi' = \pi \restriction S'$. A bisimulation with the desired properties is the relation $\rho \subseteq S \times S'$ such that $s\rho s' \Leftrightarrow s' \in S' \wedge  s \in [s']_\pi$.

I have just two questions: Firstly, where does the set $S'$ come from? I guess its existence is somehow derived via some application of separation axioms on the quotient set of $S$ under the equivalence relation of having the same $\pi$-image. Secondly, why does the equation $S= \bigcup_{s' \in S'}[s']_\pi$ hold after all? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'equivalence relation of having the same $\pi$-image' is called the *kernel* of the function $\pi$, and as you say, it is an *equivalence relation*. 
(Note that the codomain of the function doesn't matter here.)

As for every equivalence relation, the base set gets fully partitioned by the equivalence classes.

For constructing $S'$, in general, the *axiom of choice* is needed: we simultaneously choose an element from each equivalence class.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The construction of $S'$ has some strong non-constructive flavor, so I guessed that choice principles might play a role.